# How to send JSON data to my wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 websites.
Website A (normal PHP, HTML website).
Website B (wordpress).
I need to post JSON data from website A to website B. I need to know how to set up a URL in my website B which can be used in POST action in Website A.

Comment: What have you tried? See how to ask a question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far, so we can help you debug or improve it. That's how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents()` or `php cURL`. Reference for cURL is given below:

First, Add an `api.php` on your website A.

**api.php**

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['key'] != '555')
{
    $final = array('error' => 'Invalid Key');
    echo json_encode($final);
    exit();
}
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_a";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

//update, del, get by id, get all
switch($action)
{   


    case 'get_all':
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_a';
        $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $final = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
        {
            $final[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($final);
        break;


    default:
        $final = array('error' => 'Invalid Command');
        echo json_encode($final);
}
?>
```

Next, add following code in your website B.

```
<?php
 $cSession = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://yoursite.com/api.php?key=555&action=get_all");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
curl_close($cSession);
$arr = json_decode($result);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

You may make more secure or may tweak it in your way adding more functions to insert, del, get by id but this is the basic idea. Hope it helps. :)